# Wave Dashboards - Values Table lens

Tags: einstein-analytics

I am struggling with the order of how fields are shown in a Values Table within a Dashboard, how can I get them to appear in an order that makes sense to the end user?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific

For now:
ordering columns is straight forward you drag the column to a position you want in the left sidebar for changing the header value you can change it in saql query. for filtering use filter condition